# Custom annotation in symfony 3 controller

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine

So the question is pretty straightforward. I have a code in my controller that has became redundant, and i've decided to make the annotation for it.

```
if (!$request->getContentType() === 'json' ) {
    return new JsonResponse(array('success' => false));
}
$content = $request->getContent();

if(empty($content)){
    throw new BadRequestHttpException("Content is empty");
}
$data = json_decode($content, true);
if(empty($data) || !array_key_exists('type', $data)) {
    return new JsonResponse(array('success' => false));
}
```

How do i make custom annotation `@CheckRequest` in which I can use the $request object as a parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make a custom annotation and then a listener that injects the annotation reader and handles the **kernel.controller** event:

### Annotation

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class CheckRequest
{
}
```

### Service Definition

```
services:
    controller_check_request:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\ControllerCheckRequestListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController}
        arguments:
            - "@annotation_reader"
```

### Listener:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Annotation\CheckRequest;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;

class ControllerCheckRequestListener
{
    /** @var Reader */
    private $reader;

    /**
     * @param Reader $reader
     */
    public function __construct(Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (!is_array($controllers = $event->getController())) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $content = $request->getContent();

        list($controller, $methodName) = $controllers;

        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($controller);
        $classAnnotation = $this->reader
            ->getClassAnnotation($reflectionClass, CheckRequest::class);

        $reflectionObject = new \ReflectionObject($controller);
        $reflectionMethod = $reflectionObject->getMethod($methodName);
        $methodAnnotation = $this->reader
            ->getMethodAnnotation($reflectionMethod, CheckRequest::class);

        if (!($classAnnotation || $methodAnnotation)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($request->getContentType() !== 'json' ) {
            return $event->setController(
                function() {
                    return new JsonResponse(['success' => false]);
                }
            );
        }

        if (empty($content)) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Content is empty');
        }

        $data = json_decode($content, true);

        if ($request->getContentType() !== 'json' ) {
            return $event->setController(
                function() {
                    return new JsonResponse(['success' => false]);
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that instead of returning the response, you set the entire controller with `$event->setController();`, and you also must `return` when making that call.

Then in your controller you can set it on the entire class:

```
use AppBundle\Annotation\CheckRequest;

/**
 * @CheckRequest
 */
class YourController extends Controller
{
}
```

or individual methods/actions:

```
use AppBundle\Annotation\CheckRequest;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     * @CheckRequest
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind I haven't specifically tested this so if you discover a small bug or something, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: Hey Jason, thank for the quick answer. I found a small bug. It seems like the FilterControllerEvent does not have setResponse method.

Comment: Ah, right.  I updated the function call, I think it requires `setController()` instead. Give that a shot.

Comment: Also, one more thing, i think you missunderstood my intention. I wasn't going to use annotation on entire controller, only on some methods. So i think that it should go something like this: 
        $object = new \ReflectionObject($controller[0]);// get controller
        $method = $object->getMethod($controller[1]);
And then foreach of those methods i need to extract the annotations via this->reader->getMethodAnnotations($method)...
Thanks for the answers, i appreciate it alot. :)

Comment: I updated the answer - it *should* work and allow you to specify it either for the entire controller class or a specific controller action now.

Comment: Hi again Jason, sorry to be bugging you, but could you please explain to me how would i insert a value into a parameter, by using annotations? Same as the @ParamConverter does? Do i use ReflectionParameter and then do something with it or what?
Again sorry if i'm much of a bother, but i'm a beginner, and currently working on a application which is for a job interview. Also the code where you return json response inside of a setController doesnt work, so instead i throw a custom exception i made and exception listener in which i'm setting that json response, so now it's working with that.

Comment: You shouldn't have to throw the custom exception with the exception listener, although what you did is a perfectly acceptable way to perform your action and also good practice to learn, seeing as you are a beginner.  I updated the code to work properly, I was missing a `return` statement.  As to your additional question, I don't want to be doing your job interview's code for you.  However, I would encourage you to ask another question on StackOverflow and post some examples of what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**For Symfony 3.4.***

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event){

    if (!is_array($controllers = $event->getController())) {
        return;
    }

    list($controller, $methodName) = $controllers;

    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($controller);

    // Controller
    $reader = new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader();
    $classAnnotation = $reader->getClassAnnotation($reflectionClass, AnnotationClass::class);

    // Method
    $reflectionMethod = $reflectionClass->getMethod($methodName);
    $methodAnnotation = $reader->getMethodAnnotation($reflectionMethod, AnnotationClass::class);

    if(!($classAnnotation || $methodAnnotation)){
        return;
    }

    /** TODO CODE HERE **/
}
```